# how to setup proguard for my android project

Tags: android, proguard

i am not able to configure proguard for my project. Following are the error that i am getting while i am trying to compile.

```
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager$CaptionStyle
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Style
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder addAction(int,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification build()' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setPriority(int)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setStyle(android.app.Notification$Style)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.b: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Fragment getParentFragment()' in class android.app.Fragment
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService$a: can't find referenced class android.app.AppOpsManager
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService$a: can't find referenced class android.app.AppOpsManager
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.games.internal.PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1: can't find referenced method 'android.view.Display getDisplay()' in class android.view.View
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.games.internal.PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1: can't find referenced method 'void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnGlobalLayoutListener)' in class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.an$2: can't find referenced method 'void evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback)' in class android.webkit.WebView
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.fw: can't find referenced method 'boolean isActiveNetworkMetered()' in class android.net.ConnectivityManager
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gp: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getDefaultUserAgent(android.content.Context)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gp: can't find referenced method 'void setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gv: can't find referenced method 'void evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback)' in class android.webkit.WebView
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.Utils: can't find referenced class android.net.LinkProperties
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.Utils: can't find referenced class android.net.LinkProperties
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: there were 22 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: there were 12 unresolved references to program class members.
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-02-20 23:42:12 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Style
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder addAction(int,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification build()' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setPriority(int)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setStyle(android.app.Notification$Style)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.b: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Fragment getParentFragment()' in class android.app.Fragment
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService$a: can't find referenced class android.app.AppOpsManager
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService$a: can't find referenced class android.app.AppOpsManager
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.games.internal.PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1: can't find referenced method 'android.view.Display getDisplay()' in class android.view.View
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.games.internal.PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1: can't find referenced method 'void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnGlobalLayoutListener)' in class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.an$2: can't find referenced method 'void evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback)' in class android.webkit.WebView
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.fw: can't find referenced method 'boolean isActiveNetworkMetered()' in class android.net.ConnectivityManager
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gp: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getDefaultUserAgent(android.content.Context)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gp: can't find referenced method 'void setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gv: can't find referenced method 'void evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback)' in class android.webkit.WebView
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.Utils: can't find referenced class android.net.LinkProperties
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.Utils: can't find referenced class android.net.LinkProperties
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: there were 13 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: there were 12 unresolved references to program class members.
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-02-20 23:44:06 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
[2015-02-20 23:46:31 - test] C:\My Drive\ultimatesid wrkspace\test\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-02-20 23:46:31 - test] 
[2015-02-20 23:46:31 - test] C:\My Drive\ultimatesid wrkspace\test\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-02-20 23:46:31 - test] 
[2015-02-20 23:46:31 - test] C:\My Drive\ultimatesid wrkspace\test\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-02-20 23:46:31 - test] 
[2015-02-20 23:47:20 - test] C:\My Drive\ultimatesid wrkspace\test\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-02-20 23:47:20 - test] 
[2015-02-20 23:47:20 - test] C:\My Drive\ultimatesid wrkspace\test\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2015-02-20 23:47:20 - test] 
[2015-02-20 23:47:20 - test] C:\My Drive\ultimatesid wrkspace\test\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2015-02-20 23:47:20 - test] 
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$Style
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder addAction(int,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification build()' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setPriority(int)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setStyle(android.app.Notification$Style)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.b: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Fragment getParentFragment()' in class android.app.Fragment
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService$a: can't find referenced class android.app.AppOpsManager
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService$a: can't find referenced class android.app.AppOpsManager
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.games.internal.PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1: can't find referenced method 'android.view.Display getDisplay()' in class android.view.View
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.games.internal.PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1: can't find referenced method 'void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnGlobalLayoutListener)' in class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.an$2: can't find referenced method 'void evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback)' in class android.webkit.WebView
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.fw: can't find referenced method 'boolean isActiveNetworkMetered()' in class android.net.ConnectivityManager
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gp: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getDefaultUserAgent(android.content.Context)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gp: can't find referenced method 'void setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(boolean)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.gv: can't find referenced method 'void evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,android.webkit.ValueCallback)' in class android.webkit.WebView
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.Utils: can't find referenced class android.net.LinkProperties
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.Utils: can't find referenced class android.net.LinkProperties
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.WebViewProxySettings: can't find referenced class android.util.ArrayMap
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: there were 13 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: there were 12 unresolved references to program class members.
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-02-20 23:48:08 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
[2015-02-20 23:50:13 - PsiphonAndroid] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-02-20 23:50:13 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.Utils: can't find referenced class android.net.LinkProperties
[2015-02-20 23:50:13 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: com.psiphon3.psiphonlibrary.Utils: can't find referenced class android.net.LinkProperties
[2015-02-20 23:50:13 - PsiphonAndroid]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-02-20 23:50:13 - PsiphonAndroid] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-02-20 23:50:13 - PsiphonAndroid]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-02-20 23:50:13 - PsiphonAndroid] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-02-20 23:50:13 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-02-20 23:50:13 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-02-20 23:50:13 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-02-20 23:50:13 - PsiphonAndroid]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

This is my proguard properties file:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this          (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-    project.txt
#proguard.config=proguard-project.txt
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt:proguard- project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=..\\PsiphonAndroidLibrary
 android.library.reference.2=..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\Users\\TVS\\Desktop\\codecanyon-  9585545-red-and-yellow-addictive-game-admob-integrated\\RedAndYellow\\Libraries\\google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.3=..\\..\\..\\google-play-services_lib
```

Comment: Add this in proguard and try `-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}`

Comment: The configuration of proguard is not easy and it is depends on dependencies which you use in your project and libs and some solution of your code like using reflection

Answer (score 1):

Also check if your android manifest targetSdkVersion is same with your project.properties target :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

project.properties

```
# Project target.
target=android-21
```